# Monopoly chance card "move to" utility owned by person who recieved card

Tags: monopoly

During a game a player picked up a chance card which told him to go to a utility. He however owned both utilities and it was therefore his property. He argued that the bank therefore owes him the 10× his roll. I said that he would simply owe himself the 10× dice roll. What is the rule here?

Comment: I don't think there is any instance in Monopoly where the bank pays a player rent.  I've not played in years so there may be new specificities cards not covered in rules. But it a card moves you to your own property you can't pay yourself rent, the bank does not pay you and nothing happens.

Answer (score 8):

Nothing happens (or if you want to say he owes himself money you can).  Monopoly spells out what happens in the rules fairly well.  The Chance and Community Chest cards also do a good job of explaining what should happen.  Nothing in that Chance card says anything about the Bank paying in the event the property is owned by the player.  It simply says

> If OWNED, throw dice and pay owner a total ten times the amount
>   thrown.

"Pay" is clearly an instruction to the player who drew the card, not the bank.